# Counting the number of functions an Object does

Tags: java

I have created this program/scenario.

Multiple Robots are created and then "escape" from the room that has been created. I have also created a counter to count the moves that the robots make and then form an average.

I have created all this it only wants to return 0 for some reason. It's throwing up no errors or the like so I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Here are both parts of the code:

```
public static double countingMoves;

.
.
.

public void move() {
super.move();
countingMoves++;
}

public int getRobotMoves() {
return countingMoves;
}




int Counter = EscapeBot.countingMoves/10;
```

Comment: Without even looking at the code, I'll guess that you're performing integer division when you calculate your average.  If both the numerator and the denominator are ints, the result of the division will always be an int (and probably zero).  Try casting one of those numbers to a double before you divide.

Comment: @jahroy ah. Don't look at the code :)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code *here.* Most people are like me and won't chase links, and the question has no permanent value without the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int Counter = EscapeBot.countingMoves/10;
```

**First Point**

You're dividing two integers, which as stated in the comments, will result to 0 is the result is < 0. Cast one of these types to a double. This process is called [Arithmetic Promotion](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/21.html), where every element in an expression has it's precision increased to the element with the highest precision. E.g:

```
int / int = int
double / double = double
int / double = double
int + String = String
```

For your code:

```
double Counter = EscapeBox.countingMoves/10.0;
```

**Second Point**

The Java naming convention states that the first word of variables or methods that are not constants must begin with a lower case letter.

```
Counter -> counter
```

**Third and hopefully final point**

If you look at where you are computing the average, `0.0` is actually correct. You compute the average at the start, before you have any moves.

```
double Counter = EscapeBot.countingMoves/10.0;
// When computed at the start, this equals:
// double Counter = EscapeBot.countingMoves(0)/10.0 = 0/10.0 = 0.0
```

Comes before any moves. By putting this at the end of your code, you should get a more accurate reading.

Comment: Yes... Note to new programmers: **Please follow naming conventions!**  I don't understand why professors don't enforce this.  I would go crazy if I taught a class and every student made up their own style!  It seems like splitting hairs to newbs, but it makes a **HUGE** difference when others read your code.

Comment: @Chris It actually still doesn't work. It just returns 0.0 for some reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you send me the link to the `gist` again?

Comment: @Strobe_ - Did you add the `.0` to the end of the denominator?

Comment: @ChrisCooney Of courses, I just used the code that you provided, is there something wrong with my EscapeBot methods?

Comment: If you did add the `.0`, then could you please print out the value in `countingMoves` and tell us?

Comment: @ChrisCooney "The average number of moves is 0.0"

Comment: That's not `countingMoves`. I mean the total number of moves; not the average.

Comment: @ChrisCooney My apologies. 
"3
14
16
18
28
30
34
40
48
51"

Comment: Errr Ok. Lets pretend this never happened! Thanks alot though, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm afraid it is forever immortalized in SO. But we all have off days. No worries :)